# Create regular expression for

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression to accept

an integer

> 123

or

an integer then underscore then another integer

> 123_45

Here is what I have

```
/^[0-9]+_*[0-9]*$/
```

how do i make `_*[0-9]*` (the second part) optional

Comment: `_*` matches none, one OR MORE underscores `_?` Is one or none

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use this regular expression `^\d+(_\d+)?$`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
/^[0-9]+(_[0-9]+)?$/
```

Optional syntax `()?` taken from http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html

But as stated in the accepted answer `\d` can be used as shorthand for `[0-9]` so this could be

```
/^\d+(_\d+)?$/
```

Comment: Great! appreciate the link.

Comment: Updated to avoid match of 123_ and also 123___456

Answer (score 0):

check this expression,

> /^[0-9]+(_([0-9])+)?$/

it will not match 123_

Comment: it will match 1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1